# How do I write a SQL Like statement that includes : and %?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, jinja2

I am trying to run a SQL query written as a python string to a function that connects to a DB and returns the results.

When doing so, I get this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ')', got ':'
```

My query looks like this:

```
query = """
SELECT *
FROM test_db
where text_message LIKE '{{image:%}}'
"""
```

The column value I am trying to return starts with `{{image:` then has some random value and ends with `}}`.

Any idea why this is happening? I know it's because of the way the LIKE is written but to me it looks like I have followed all syntax rules. It clearly doesn't like something around the `:` and `%`

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Try replacing `LIKE '{{image:%}}'` with `LIKE '{{image}}' || '%'`, but this syntax depends on the specific database as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using jinja2 in some other parts of your code
In this particular instance you should try to ignore the string with:

**Escaping**

*documentation: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#escaping*

It is sometimes desirable to have Jinja ignore parts it would otherwise handle as variables or blocks. For example, if, with the default syntax, you want to use {{ as a raw string in a template and not start a variable, you have to use a trick.

```
{% raw %}
       query = """
       SELECT *
       FROM test_db
       where text_message LIKE '{{image:%}}'
       """
{% endraw %}
```